# GTMAppAuth throwing error «unable to open Safari»

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to implement GTMAppAuth via Cocoapods into my app.

But when I try to start the process with this:

```
appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow = [OIDAuthState
    authStateByPresentingAuthorizationRequest:request
    externalUserAgent: userAgent
    callback:^(OIDAuthState * _Nullable authState, NSError * _Nullable error) { … }
```

I get an error saying `unable to open Safari`.

I can't find anything on the interwebs that tell me why this error occurs.

I did set the URL-scheme in the info.plist.

Any ideas?

[Edit]

I want to mention that the examples that come with the Framework seem to be wrong or at least outdated. All I can use is `OIDAuthState authStateByPresentingAuhtorizationRequest: externalUserAgent: callback` - but in the example they're using either `OIDAuthState authStateByPresentingAuthorizationRequest: callback:` or `OIDAuthState authStateByPresentingAuthorizationRequest: presentingViewController: callback` - I can't access these in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of struggle, I found that if you also include `pod 'AppAuth'` (which you can see [here](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS), all of a sudden you have this signature

```
[OIDAuthState authStateByPresentingAuthorizationRequest:request
  presentingViewController:self.viewController
  callback: ...
```

Comment: Thanks - it seems google doesn't think it's necessary to mention this in their docs.